# Add Values to a Row of TreeList of DevExpress

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtratreelist

I am creating an application and used a TreeList of DevExpress.
Currently, I am the one who created the nodes of TreeList in the node editor and planned that all data will be read or transferred in my TreeList by adding it to the specified column.

How could I achieve this?

Here is my code

```
tbl.Rows.Add(4,  4, 10 );
tbl.Rows.Add(5, 5, 30);
```

but it doesn't work at all. I'm just getting an exception.

Comment: What exception does it give you..? we are not mind readers here

Comment: Hav you checked out [DevExpress](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5558) ?

Comment: Why don't you contact DX directly?

Answer (score 0):

Devexpress controls work differently than the built-in winforms controls.

Here's an example on how you could add items to your `TreeView` in an unbound manner:

```
using DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Columns;
using DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Nodes;

public class Form1
{

    private void Form1_Load(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        TreeList1.Columns.Clear();
        TreeListColumn newColumn = TreeList1.Columns.Add();
        newColumn.Caption = "Tree Column";
        newColumn.Visible = true;

        TreeList1.Nodes.Clear();
        TreeListNode rootNode = TreeList1.Nodes.Add({ "Root Node" });
        TreeListNode child1 = rootNode.Nodes.Add({ "Child 1" });
        child1.Nodes.Add({ "GrandChild 1.1" });
        child1.Nodes.Add({ "GrandChild 1.2" });

        TreeListNode child2 = rootNode.Nodes.Add({ "Child 2" });
        child2.Nodes.Add({ "GrandChild2.1" });
        child2.Nodes.Add({ "GrandChild2.2" });
        child2.Nodes.Add({ "GrandChild2.3" });

        TreeList1.RefreshNode(rootNode);
    }
}
```

If you need more code samples, click below - you'll find plenty of them there:

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5558

Comment: Thank you for answering..
how could i achieve this having a database..?
what is the process to deal with?

Comment: The link is posted above in my answer should put in you in the right direction. What have you tried so far?